# Bentley-McIlroy 3-way partitioning

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, partitioning, quicksort

The following is the `Hoare` partitioning algorithm I have written to partition an array based on a given pivot (in this case, it is the first element of the array, a rather poor choice!). However, the `Bentley-McIlroy 3-way partitioning` at http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/static/QuicksortIsOptimal.pdf claims to give better performance when a number of keys are equal. Can anyone explain briefly what the code on page 9 achieves, and why it performs better than the `Hoare` algorithm? And one question, the partitioning places elements based on `<`, `=` and `>`. What if the element which is present multiple times isn't the pivot?

```
def hoare(arr,start,end):
     pivot = arr[start]
     i,j = start,end
     while i < j:
        while i < j and arr[i] <= pivot:
            i += 1
        while j >= i and arr[j] > pivot:
            j -= 1
        if i < j:
            arr[i],arr[j] = arr[j],arr[i]
     arr[start],arr[j] = arr[j],arr[start]
     return j
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code on page 9 is, I think, explained pretty well by the diagram on page 8: you first do the partition, but also swap elements equal to the pivot to the edges of the vector, so it ends up as:

```
[equals-left] [lesses] [greaters] [equals-right]
```

Then you swap the equal elements back to the centre:

```
[lesses] [equals-left] [equals-right] [greaters]
```

Then you recursively sort `[lesses]` and `[greaters]`

Sedgwick's assumption is that there are many elements which are repeated in the dataset. In that case, it will be common for the pivot to be repeated, and if it is you can achieve some benefit by not including any of the repetitions of the pivot in either of the quicksort recursions, so that the size of the sum of the two partitions will be less than the size of the vector by the number of repetitions of the pivot (even if it is just by itself.) That reduces the number of elements you need to recurse over, which makes the recursion faster.

The cost of doing this is one or two extra comparisons per element, although both of them simply repeat previous comparisons with a different success condition. In the case that comparison is complicated, you might want to use an explicit three-way compare function in order to be able to save the result of the last < compares (in the while loops in Sedgwick's code). If the pivot is not repeated, then that is precisely the extra cost: those extra comparisons. If the pivot is repeated, then there is one or two extra swaps and two or one extra comparisons (so three extra operations, if swap and compare take the same amount of time) for each repeated pivot element, plus the two extra comparisons for every other element.

Is this worth it? I'm skeptical, but if Sedgwick says it is, then you should probably listen to him rather than me.

Comment: :) Sedgwick does look like *the* authority on algorithms, eh? Can you tell me what will be the complexity of this partitioning method, when applied to an array of length `l` and first element as the pivot?

Comment: On average, it will be `O(N log N)`, (using N instead of l because it looks less like a one), just like the standard algorithm. The question Sedgwick posits is how the algorithm performs on vectors with a small number of distinct elements (`n` in Sedgwick's slides is the number of distinct elements). The standard algorithm is O(N<sup>2</sup>) if n is one, but the modified algorithm in that case is O(N). In general, for very small n, the standard algorithm performs poorly because it eventually reaches a partition whose values are all equal, the n=1 case.

Comment: How come the partitioning is giving `O(log N)` time?

Comment: sorry, misunderstood; I thought you were talking about the use of the partitions. The partitioning is always linear, regardless of which method you use. That should be clear because each element in the vector except the pivot element itself is examined exactly once, and the examination consists of at most two comparisons and two swaps (for the three-way partition). The quicksorting of the partitions is between N log N and N<sup>2</sup>.

Answer (score 5):

I found that it's possible to implement the 3-way partition based on N. Lumoto's idea, which is a bit easier. (As Jon Bentley mentioned in his book `Programming pearls', Lumoto's method is straightforward).

The idea is to keep an invariant during the scan, that at any time the elements which are less than the pivot are put to the left most section, while the elements equal to the pivot are next to that section, the elements which are greater than the pivot are put to the right most. the rest part is those element haven't been examined yet.

These sections are bounded by `i`, `k`, and `j`. When we examine an element, if it is equal to the pivot, we just advance to the next one, if it's less than the pivot, we can exchange it with the first one on the ‘equal’ section, so that the invariant can be resumed. Otherwise, we need keep exchanging it with the last one in front of the greater section.

```C
/*
 * Another 3-way partition ternary quick sort based on N. Lomuto's method.
 *   Invariant: ... less ... | ... equal ... | ... ? ... | greater |
 *                           i               k           j
 */
void qsort3(Key* xs, int l, int u) {
    int i, j, k; Key pivot;
    if (l < u - 1) {
        i = l; j = u; pivot = xs[l];
        for (k = l + 1; k < j; ++k) {
            while (pivot < xs[k]) { --j; swap(xs[j], xs[k]); }
            if (xs[k] < pivot) { swap(xs[i], xs[k]); ++i; }
        }
        qsort3(xs, l, i);
        qsort3(xs, j, u);
    }
}
```

I tested this program with 100,000 elements against the qsort API in standard library.

Comment: Larry, I tested this qsort3() implementation on an array of 256*256 32 bit integers and the sort performed significantly worse than the bentley-mcilroy implementation. The data I am sorting contains lots and lots of duplicate values.